# GroupLayout Java

Tags: java, swing

Using grouplayout how do you make one field expand the length of three parents?this is what i currently have. what i want to do is a add a textbox that will stretch the length of the box underthese three items. Ihow do i do that?

```
layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addComponent(puzzleNumber)
        .addComponent(newPuzzleButton)
        .addComponent(newPuzzleNumber));            

layout.linkSize(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, newPuzzleButton, newPuzzleNumber);

layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(BASELINE)
            .addComponent(puzzleNumber)
            .addComponent(newPuzzleButton)
            .addComponent(newPuzzleNumber))
```

Comment: I suggest to use [WindowBuilder](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/quick_start).

Answer (score 0):

Use a Box and set the preferredSize of the other two components in the panel.

```
Box box = Box.createHorizontalBox();
```